# how to search for specific word from end of file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a huge log file and want to search for the text "exception threw by :: " from the end of the file and get couple more characters from there. Basically I am interested in the last occurrence only.

for example if the log file is like

some data exception threw by :: classA
some more text exception threw by :: classBB
some other logs recent ones exception threw by :: classX

I want to find and print exception threw by :: classX

Kindly help.

Comment: Does "threw by :: classX" always appear on one line? Is the log file line by line or a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will search for the text you want `$TEXT` from the log `data.txt`, show X lines before and show Y lines after the match. The `tail` command will filter out all but the last match. The number used in the `tail` command is Z, and Z = X + Y + 1

```
grep -BX -AY "$TEXT" data.txt | tail -Z
```

So, for example, if you want to find `:: classX`, you want one line before and 5 lines after, then you would run

```
grep -B1 -A5 ':: classX' data.txt | tail -7
```

As a side note, if you want the first match you can replace `tail` with `head`. If you want to see all matches, remove the `| tail -Z` part.

You can add color matching also with `grep --color`

Comment: Its works. Thanks, john

Answer (score 1):

A sed solution

```
sed '/:: classX/h;$!d' logfile
```

sed matches the pattern and places the line in the hold buffer `h` then deletes all the lines except the last line `$!d` .

Answer (score 1):

Try this. First we reverse the file line by line, then reverse each line. Then search for the reverse of 'exception threw by :: ', then print the first match. And finally reverse that.

```
tac logfile.txt | rev | grep -Po '\w+\s+::\s+yb\s+werht\s+noitpecxe'  | head -1 | rev
```

This method is particularly useful for *very* large files with possibly *very* long lines because the search is done backwards and you don't have to grep through the entire file.

Comment: I wanted to find the last occurrence of "exception threw by :: " then also capture couple more characters. "ClassX" is not constant and random values are expected. My intension is to find out what is the value post the ::

Comment: Edited answer based on your comments.